# How to tag a question about the universal laws

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked a [question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/105/how-does-alchemy-work) about the universal law of a manga. Similar to 'our' universal law of gravity we have in 'our' own universe.

I was wondering whether I should use a tag to indicate that the question is about the rules of the universe of that manga?

And what tag that would that be?

- [rules](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) seems a bit unclear
- [universe](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universe) might relate to the universe itself instead of the 'universal' rules.
- [law](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) might relate to laws, judges, and so on

Answer (score 5):

Just tag with the name of the manga or anime itself. Experts in that manga or anime will know about its rules inherently. No one is an expert in rules of completely disjoint things *in general*. That's impossible. People can only be experts on specific subjects. Tag with the subject that the expert would know about, and leave it at that.

Comment: People who are interested in the universal laws of different artworks might benefit by such a tag. For example when comparing them.

Comment: @Veger: [tag:tropes], or more specifically [tag:character-abilities]?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail [tag:character-abilities] is nice, but (obviously) limited to characters.

Answer (score -3):

I'd go with [scene](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scene), Scene describes the world of the artwork in question, so it seems best appropriate here.

Comment: Thank you for your input. But, in my opinion, a disadvantage of scene is that it might refer to the graphical artwork. The amount of details, colors, etc.

Answer (score -3):

After some thoughts, I would stick with [univere-law](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/univere-law)

Although it is a bit long and not very 'pretty', it is clear at the first glance.

[univeral-law](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/univeral-law) seems to 'prettier', but it might also indicate that the question is about 'inter-artwork' laws/rules...